# JS code linked to a "close" button on a modal popup

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Unfortunately I cannot post a working code/example because it's part of a huge HTML template and I cannot extract only the interesting part :( sorry for that.

Anyway, I have this popup that I define like this:

```
<a id='bookShopping' class="popup-text" href="#book-shopping-dialog"></a>
<div id="book-shopping-dialog" class="mfp-dialog mfp-hide">
    random popup text...
    <button>Close the popup!!!</button>
</div>
```

and that I call with

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById('bookShopping').click(); return false;" >PopUp!</a>
```

The popup itself has a "X" close button on the upper right corner, defined with

```
<button class="mfp-close">X</button>
```

I want MY BUTTON, inside the "random text", to be able to close the popup as well.
I tried:

1) Give my button the mfp-close class.
**NOPE**. My button will jump to the upper right corner

2) Setting the div to display:none and/or display:block
**NOPE**. The popup will close but IT WILL NEVER REAPPEAR.

So, my last resort would be to call the same code that the "mfp-close" class is calling. My problem is that I can only find the mfp-close class defined in CSS, nothing in JS.
If I try to "inspect" the "X" button, it will not give me any event linked to it, nor any JS associated with its "click".

I know that without the source code is hard to understand, but the general question is: where, in Chrome or Firefox, can I find ALL THE JS CODE EXECUTED when I click on an element?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The javascript engines in browser run the script immediately on load of the script. When you change it in inspector and save, it only saves to your temp and when you refresh, the javascript runs the file from the domain, not your temp folder so it will always run the hosted js file not the locally saved one. HTML elements on the other hand are static elements and can be changed on the fly. CSS can be applied on the fly as well.

Comment: The simplest way to go about this might be to use the `.mfp-close` class and overwrite any inherit styles with your own custom styles using a custom class to add more *specificity* to *over-qualify* any styles you want to negate or reset. So your button will look something like this: `<button class="mfp-close your-own-custom-class">Close the popup!!!</button>`. Otherwise, write your own javascript function to close this popup (although I'm sure it's obvious which solution would be the easiest ;)

Comment: If are not sure what event is called, then run the performance profiler in chrome developer tools and then click the 'x' in your text and then stop the profiler to get the profiler data. In the data sheet you can find click event and all subsequent events.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError yes I tried that route before but there were too many things to be re-defined and I simply quit trying :)

Comment: @priyadarshiswain thank you for teaching me something I did not know. I am still kind-of-new to web development, especially "debugging" the code, so I need to learn a lot :)

Comment: @ZioBit Take some time to learn about the developer tool, they are going to your best friends in debugging and performance improvement. After some time you will be able to read all those event  like those 'Operators' in Matrix were able to read the Matrix. They will be specially helpful when you are using 3rd party frameworks.

Comment: @priyadarshiswain Thank you. I can already read executables like Matrix, so I look forward to these web tools :) My best "nerd" thing in life happened in 1996. A task was looping and blocking all the others on a Motorola 68HC11, even the RS232 printouts, so no way to understand what was going on. With an oscilloscope, we went pin by pin on the CPU (address bus), calculated "by hand" which addresses they were, checked the compiler-generated .map file, and finally understood what function was looping :) That's what I call "low level programming" ahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the Magnific popup jQuery plugin, which has an **API** including a `close()` method.  You should call that method rather than try to hack around with classes.

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

```
$.magnificPopup.close();
```

Comment: kudos for understanding the plugin from the class names ;) You were right, and there were so many includes that I couldn't see the right one in the main page. But as soon as I tried to close the modal with the correct API for the plugin, it worked. Great :) Thank you